# java.util.logging can't share the logger between two classes

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I'm trying to redirect the logs from two classes (in package com.project.callcontrol) to the same file. 
This is how I initiate the logger in both the classes
private static final Logger logger =

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CCPurgeEvent.class.getName());

private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PurgeDeadCalls.class.getName());
```

This is how I'm trying to share the same file for both the classes, java.util.logging configuration

```
com.project.callcontrol.PurgeDeadCalls.useParentHandlers = false
com.project.callcontrol.PurgeDeadCalls.handlers = com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger

com.project.callcontrol.CCPurgeEvent.useParentHandlers = false
com.project.callcontrol.CCPurgeEvent.handlers = com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger

com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.pattern=/var/log/voxcallcontrol-batches/cc_purge%u.log
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.level = FINEST
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.limit=100000000
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.count=10
```

Please note that CCPurgeLogger is doing nothing, just creating the methods of parent class FileHandler(don't even know why it is there)
My problem is that I can't get the logs from both the classes in the log file, I can get logs from only one class depending on the order of configuration in my configuration file.
For example, If I move CCPurgeEvent configuration above the PurgeDeadCalls config, it works for CCPurgeEvent and not PurgeDeadCalls and the reverse happens when I switch the order.
I can't seem to understand what I'm missing, any pointers in this direction will be very helpful.

P.S: I can't change my logging framework, I know log4j and other frameworks provide more options, but in the scope of current work, I need to use java.util.logging only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you share one log file for two loggers then you have install the handler on a common parent logger and your code has to get and pin that parent logger in memory.  The first common parent is `com.project.callcontrol`.

```
com.project.callcontrol.handlers = com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger
com.project.callcontrol.PurgeDeadCalls.useParentHandlers = true
com.project.callcontrol.CCPurgeEvent.useParentHandlers = true

com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.pattern=/var/log/voxcallcontrol-batches/cc_purge%u.log
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.level = FINEST
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.limit=100000000
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.count=10
```

If you want to use your existing configuration then you have to change the implementation of your `com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger` handler to something like:

```
public class CcPurgeLogger extends Handler {

    private static volatile Handler common;
    private static long count;


    private static void create() throws IOException {
        synchronized (CcPurgeLogger.class) {
            if (common == null) {
               common = new FileHandler(); 
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    public CcPurgeLogger() throws IOException {
        create();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
        String name = record.getLoggerName();
        return ("com.project.callcontrol.PurgeDeadCalls".equals(name)
                || "com.project.callcontrol.CCPurgeEvent".equals(name))
                && common.isLoggable(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        common.publish(record);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        common.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException {
        synchronized (CcPurgeLogger.class) {
            if (common != null) {
                if (count == 1L) {
                    common.close();
                    common = null;
                }
                --count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Could you also share an example of defining a new subsystem logger in the configuration file?

Let's name the subsystem by what it does (purge) rather than what it is (some classname).

```
com.project.callcontrol.PURGE.handlers = com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger
com.project.callcontrol.PURGE.useParentHandlers = true


com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.pattern=/var/log/voxcallcontrol-batches/cc_purge%u.log
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.level = FINEST
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.limit=100000000
com.project.logging.CcPurgeLogger.count=10
```

Then inside of both the 'PurgeDeadCalls' class and the 'CCPurgeEvent' class fetch the subsystem logger by doing the following.

```
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.project.callcontrol.PURGE");
```

Comment: Hi @jmerherns, In the configuration solution you proposed, logs from other classes in the package 'com.project.callcontrol' will also start logging to the the same file, which isn't desired. I just all the logs from these two classes in one log file. Another thing I could to is pass the 'Logger' from PurgeDeadcalls to CCPurgeEvent, because CCPurgeEvent is used only from PurgeDeadCalls. I'm wondering if I would have the same problem if I was using 'log4j'

Comment: @Nitesh You have created a custom handler so you might as well create a custom filter that checks the logger name and install it.  Or just override the `isLoggable` method of your custom handler to do the filtering.  If you want to stick with just configuration then you have to turn off `.useParentHandlers` for all loggers you don't want to see.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really at a loss, can't understand why is it so complicated to use the same logger for two classes.
I don't want to modify the custome logger CCPurgeLogger and all the others classes in this package write to the root logger, so it isn't possible to disable 'useParentLogger' for all the classes and there are like 50 classes, don't want to modify all of them.
Is there no other option, will it be easier to solve with log4j??

Comment: Don't name your loggers by classname.  Name them by subsystem and have both classes fetch the same exact same named subsystem logger.

Comment: Im stil curious if it would be simpler to implement if I was using log4j

Comment: Could you also share an example of defining a new subsystem logger in the configuration file?

Comment: @Nitesh Added an example.  Both logging frameworks are organized as trees so publishing to a sibling is still a challenge.

Comment: wow, in the end, it was much simpler to do it, if I knew that problem was only with hierarchy of loggers, I would have changed it long time back. Thanks @jmehrens for guiding me on this